# ¿Por qué no funciona mi modmail en 2 servidores distintos?

Tags: python, discord.py

Hace poco comencé a programar un modmail y me topé con un gran problema. Aquí les dejo el código:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


#PREFIJOS E INTENTS
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.guild_reactions = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.messages = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="x-",intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Listo")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="Dev = PingüiMaya14")) #CONFIGURA EL TEXTO DE LA ACTIVIDAD QUE ESTÁ HACIENDO

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def react(ctx ):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hola")
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("ADMIN")
async def setup(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel("mod-mail")
    msg = await ctx.send("Canal Creado - Configura los roles que tenga acceso en la configuración del chat")
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")



#modmail
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    empty_array = []
    modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="mod-mail")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await modmail_channel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]")

            for file in files:
                await modmail_channel.send(file.url)
        else:
            await modmail_channel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + message.content)

    elif str(message.channel) == "mod-mail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
        member_object = message.mentions[0]
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]")

            for file in files:
                await member_object.send(file.url)
        else:
            index = message.content.index(" ")
            string = message.content
            mod_message = string[index:]
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]" + mod_message)

   await client.process_commands(message)




client.run("TOKEN")
```

Quiero que el modmail **funcione en más de 2 servidores distintos**. El problema es el siguiente:

- Cuando uno al bot en 2 distintos servidores el mensaje que le mando al bot se envía al primer servidor, en mi caso **quiero que el bot deje elegir en qué servidor se quiere enviar esa pregunta**.

Ejemplo: El usuario está unido en dos servidores: server1 y server2, y el bot está unido en más servidores.

Primero el usuario le escribiría por privado al bot, luego el bot le mandaría un mensaje así:

```
En que servidor quieres mandar el mensaje 
1 - server1
2 - server2
```

Luego el bot pondría para reaccionar y depende de lo que reacciona le diría *el usuario seleccionó 1 (server1)*. El bot le diría *comienza escribir tus mensajes*, a continuación se enviaría a servidor1, luego el bot cuando el usuario ponga el comando `x-close` el bot contestaría *MD - Terminado*, y luego cuando vuelva a enviar el mensaje le daría la opción de elegir el servidor. Cuando el bot se apague se reiniciarían las opciones de todos y regresaría a preguntarles.

Comment: observación: no le veo mucho sentido a que el bot interactúe entre servidores

Comment: @Christian mi idea es hacer algo como http://modmail.xyz/

Comment: para saber a que servidores se quiere mandar el mensaje tendrás que obtener la lista de servidores en que el bot esta unido

Comment: @Christian como puedo hacerlo ?

Comment: supongo que debería estar en la propiedad guild, o algo parecido. No llegué muy lejos haciendo bots en python, por lo que solo puedo guiarte en la lógica

Comment: @Christian ahorita voy a buscarlo en la documentacion de discord.py https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127807/discussion-between-christian-and-pingui-maya).